# Trying to Multiply in Android

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to make a simple converter that multiplies a value entered by 2.2 but i am having problems getting the result to a text view. The error I am getting says 'cannot resolve method setText(Double). any advice?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    double result =0;
    double a = Double.parseDouble(weightEntered.getText().toString().trim());
    double b = 2.2;
    if(v == button_convert)
    {
        if(lbs_kg.isChecked() == true)
            result = (a * b);
            t1.setText(result);
        if(kg_lbs.isChecked() == true)
            t1.setText("Selected is : "+kg_lbs.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your double to a String.

This is important, because [setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) exists in multiple overloaded signatures.

The signature that you are using in your question is using a String Resource ID! You need to firstly turn that number into a String so that the TextView knows how to use it properly.

```
String str = String.valueOf(result);
t1.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = (a * b);
t1.setText(String.format("%.2f", result))
```

Using `String.format()` allows you to control the precision for the output value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your double value to string because `setText()` can set only text value to it's view.
update this line

```
  t1.setText(result);
```

to
 `t1.setText(String.valueOf(result));`

Comment: Tell him *why* that matters. Also `String.valueOf(result)` works too.

Comment: this is also solution but not proper way to do this!

Comment: @user3091082, As mentioned above, this is not a good approach to convert a number to a String. Check the other answer and update your code.

Comment: @user3091082 update your code as per my updated answer because older method was not right to do so and mark correct green sign so that other users can get answer of their question.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: @user3091082 accept answer by putting correct sign to answer

Comment: Thanks again for the help, does anyone know how to round the value to a whole number?